# PostgreSQL: Usage synonym dictionary as table

Tags: postgresql, dictionary

Is it possible use (instead text file synonym dictionary) table with two columns? Synonym dictionary often changed, regenerate dictionary and replacement impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No that isn't possible. A synonym dictionary can only be created from a file, not from a table (unless you change the PostgreSQL source).

Note that when you change the definition of a dictionary, you have to rebuild all indexes that use it, and you have to update all `tsvector` columns generated by triggers.